# How to display IMCE file browser in overlay or popup window?

Tags: modal-dialogs, files

When users access the IMCE file browser from their user profile it gets integrated in the websites main content. I want it to be displayed in the administrative overlay or even as a popup. Does anyone know how to do that?

I have checked the configuration settings, but it doesn't seem to be that easy, or I overlooked something. I also checked the module ThemeKey, but I think that would be a little overkill.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also very curious how this can be achieved.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just accepted the default way as the project was too small to invest too much time on details.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Media module](http://drupal.org/project/media) instead of IMCE provides a powerful popup media asset browser that integrates with WYSIWYG.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an iframe with src=yoursite.com/imce. The iframe can be displayed anywhere in the page including the popups.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on this with examples?  As it stands, although correct, is a relatively poor quality answer. [answer] has some pretty good advice for putting together a good quality, solid answer :-)